# Prove that Least squares and decorrelator are equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, least-squares

Here is the problem:

$$\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{Ax}+\mathbf{b}$$

where
$\mathbf{y,x,b}$ are vectors, and$\mathbf{A}$ is matrix(generally rectangular, **but with full column rank**).

The least squre solution is denoted by:

$$\hat{\mathbf{x}}=\mathbf{A^+y} \quad (1)$$.

Now my problem is to prove that the $i$-th component of $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$, $\hat{x}_i$ is given by:

$$\bf \frac{a_i^H(I-A_iA_i^+)}{||(I-A_iA_i^+)a_i||^2} y\quad (2)$$

where $\bf a_i$ is the $i$-th column of $\bf A$, and $\bf A_i$ is $\bf [a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_{i-1},a_{i+1},\cdots,a_n]$, i.e., $\bf A$ with $\bf a_i$ deleted.

(2) is called ``decorrelator'', i.e., it contains contribution from $ x_i$ and $\bf b$, but no contribution from $x_j, (j\neq i)$.

This is asserted in a book, But I still cannot prove it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the partitioning $A:=[B, c]\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ where $B$ has $n-1$ columns. Since $A$ has full column rank, $A^+=(A^HA)^{-1}A^H$. We have
$$
A^HA=\pmatrix{B^HB & B^Hc\\c^HB & c^Hc}.
$$
Using the [block inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Blockwise_inversion) formula, we have (with $*$ denoting "something unimportant")
$$
(A^HA)^{-1}=\pmatrix{*&*\\-\alpha c^HB(B^HB)^{-1}&\alpha},
$$
where
$$
\alpha:=\frac{1}{c^Hc-c^HB^H(B^HB)^{-1}Bc}=\frac{1}{\|(I-BB^+)c\|_2^2}.
$$
Hence
$$
A^+=\pmatrix{*&*\\-\alpha c^HB(B^HB)^{-1}&\alpha}\pmatrix{B^H\\c^H}
$$
and the last row of $A^+$ is given by
$$
\alpha c^H[I-B(B^HB)^{-1}B^H]=\frac{c^H(I-BB^+)}{\|(I-BB^+)c\|_2^2}.
$$
You can see that this last row of $A^+$ has the same form as the fraction in (2) for $i=n$. To prove the general statement, you can consider a permutation matrix $P$ such that $AP$ has $a_i$ in the last column and use the fact that $(AP)^+=P^TA^+$.

Comment: @Pavel: Wonderful, I like your proof!. But the second display formula is a typo, the inverse should be parenthesized. :)

Comment: @Maple Ah, yes. Indeed :)